# Multi-tenancy in SugarCRM

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am looking for a multi tenant solution with  sugarcrm.

Please note that,I don't like to go with creating multiple Sugarcrms instances.

In fact, I want to offer a solution for multiple organizations with different contacts, clients ... etc.

I am using SugarCE-Full-6.5.14(Community Edition) version of sugarcrm. Is that possible with this version of sugar?.

I have seen several links about the same,but unfortunately i could not get a solution from those links..

Any one please provide some useful informations about the same or what changes i need to be made in this version to manage multiple organizations ?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of reasons why it isn't a good idea to use SugarCRM, as-is, for multi-tenant purposes. See:

http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.com/2010/09/sugarcrm-101-how-do-i-manage-multiple.html
http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.com/2013/03/sugarcrm-101-multiple-businesses.html

If you really want to force it to work you would need something to keep the data segregated like SecuritySuite: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite

But there will always be potential holes. It is best to just spin up a new instance for each customer.

Comment: Ok Thanks egg..
How can be possible to have multiple 'companies' without installing multiple Sugarcrm CE's? Thus can one have a  www.xsw.com/x ,                www.xsw.com/y, www.xsw.com/z etc.... all sitting on a single server and one is not able to see the other ( x doesn't know of y)?

If so how is this possible is there a pdf or html that explains the steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes edaklij - It is very much possible to have www.xsw.com/x , www.xsw.com/y, www.xsw.com/z etc, what you just need is a webserver where www.xsw.com pointed to main root directory, and within that you have sub-directories x, y ,z etc. Now each of sub directory contains one complete Sugar instance, and you are done.

bipul